# Who is known to worship Bahamut besides dragons?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities

I have been researching to create a character background in D&D 5e of a Draconic bloodline sorcerer Tiefling noble (a stretch I know, but I have an idea to make it work). I cannot seem to find a description in any wikis of followers of Bahamut other than dragons. I am not set on making him religious, but it would help my character in his drive to be a better individual, and bring honor to his now-disgraced house. I am wondering if there is any other info in other material I do not have access to about the followers of Bahamut.

Comment: Is lore from previous editions OK?  Does the lore have to be Forgotten Realms?

Comment: (It is still network policy to remove greetings/taglines/thanks. Such edits are considered helpful improvements, as they reduce noise in the stream of information future readers have to wade through when using our Q&A database. A year from now readers want to read the Q to see if it matches their problem and don’t care if once upon a time the answer-writers were thanked ahead of time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you want your character to be a follower of Bahamut, that doesn't necessarily require *all his people* to follow Bahamut.

For example, he could have been rescued by a follower of Bahamut, he could have had some kind of vision, he could have touched a holy relict of Bahamut that created a special connection between them, etc etc etc.

Also, your character is a *Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer*, that's a ton of story hooks available right there, depending on the background story of why that's your bloodline.
Although, as a side note: depending on how much you want to go Bahamut, the *Divine Soul Sorcerer* from *Xanathar's Guide To Everything*, page 50, might be relevant for you as well.

---

#### Anyhow, the bottom line is: think outside the box.

Just because your character isn't a dragon (for obvious reasons) or a *Dragonborn* doesn't mean he can't be a follower of Bahamut. There might be some lore out there about non-dragon(born) followers of Bahamut*, but the easiest solution is to just create it yourself!

*I'm pretty sure that'd be previous editions, though. I don't think something like that is mentioned in the 5e rulebooks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95263/discussion-on-answer-by-pixelmaster-who-is-known-to-worship-bahamut-besides-drag). (You may also want to edit your answer to include some of your clarifications/suggestions from your earlier comments.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently updating an old 2e character who adventured in Krynn (Dragonlance) and was a cleric of Paladine. Paladine is *so* much like Bahamut (and, in fact, one of the names listed for Paladine in Krynn is Bah'mut). Whether or not Bahamut and Paladine *are* the same entity is actually something of a heated debate, but I figure, at the very least, they would be on friendly terms, so if a Krynnish cleric of Paladine entered another realm where Bahamut held sway, that Bahamut would accept the cleric as one of his own ... and that's assuming the two entities are *not* different projections of the same entity.

So, in your case, you might look into the old Dragonlance lore and base your cleric on Paladine. Having just went through the process, I can say it was a bit time consuming to figure out which spells he'd have access to when there was no obvious equivalent in the 5e lore, but I did it, and I like the results.

Might be something to consider. However, I *completely* agree with the ["bottom line" in PixelMaster's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129733/who-is-known-to-worship-bahamut-besides-dragons/129736#129736).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first answer!